# React - does a child component re-mount each time the parent component renders?

Tags: reactjs

In this very basic example I am including the component `Bar` inside the render function of component `Foo`. I am observing that the `componentDidMount` method for `Bar` is firing each time Foo re-renders - is this the correct behaviour?

```
import Bar from './Bar.jsx';

export default class Foo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Bar />
        );
    }
}
```

Note: I have asked this question to sanity check the expected behaviour, in order to track down a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The children behaviour depends on the parent behaviour.

componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. The componentDidMount() method of child components is invoked before that of parent components.

If your parent component simply re-renders, it is expected that child components also simply re-render, since componentDidMount() is invoked only once in the component's lifecycle.

Comment: Could you please clean this answer up to remove details about the parent re-mounting as the question is only concerned about re-rendering (?)

Comment: @JoeTidee Done.

Answer (score 3):

Need to be careful when using if `if/else` logic in the render function. In the example below, the `Bar` component will unmount if the `loading` prop value changes to `true`:

```
import Bar from './Bar.jsx';

export default class Foo extends Component {
    render() {
        if(this.props.loading){
            return (
                <div>Loading...</div>
            );
        }
        else{
            return (
                <Bar />
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the reasons why a child component mounts every time the parent re-renders unexpectedly are:

- Children are passed in an array of components without keys
- Children are contained in styled components that are declared within the render function. Not outside the parent component, as they should.